# Making Managed Object Context available to array controller in Storyboard scene

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, storyboard, nsarraycontroller

I have a core data, document based, storyboard OS X application.

There is a test project here:

https://github.com/ericgorr/sb_ac_doc

which is just the default project Xcode creates with a few modifications.

I have a single view controller and the view contains a table view which will eventually display the data in the Core Data document. I will also using an array controller to manage the rows for the table view.

The three scenes are:

- Application Scene
- Window Controller Scene
- Main View Controller Scene

The *Main View Controller Scene* contains the *TestItem Array Controller*.

The *TestItem View Controller* contains the code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController
{
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext?

    //
    // ...
    //    
}
```

The *TestItem Array Controller* contains the Parameters Binding:

```
Managed Object Context
    Bind to: Main View Controller
    Model Key Path: context
```

In Document.swift:

```
override func makeWindowControllers()
{
    let moc = self.managedObjectContext!

    // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
    let storyboard          = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let windowController    = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier( "Document Window Controller" ) as! NSWindowController
    let contentController   = windowController.contentViewController as! ViewController

    NSLog( "%@", self.managedObjectContext! )

    contentController.context = self.managedObjectContext!

    NSLog( "%@", contentController.context! )

    self.addWindowController( windowController )
}
```

This is my attempt to pass the MOC to the view controller before the array controller attempts to access it.

The NSLog's both print out valid values.

However, I am getting the following crash:

```
2016-03-13 20:13:02.667 sb_ac_doc[73021:16415257] Cannot perform operation without a managed object context
2016-03-13 20:13:02.669 sb_ac_doc[73021:16415257] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff956f9ae2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9a09073c objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff956f998d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c8224e7 -[_NSManagedProxy _managedObjectContext] + 66
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c822507 -[_NSManagedProxy _persistentStoreCoordinator] + 22
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c82257a -[_NSManagedProxy _entity] + 46
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c822802 -[_NSManagedProxy fetchRequestWithSortDescriptors:limit:] + 89
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c821fec -[NSObjectController(NSManagedController) _executeFetch:didCommitSuccessfully:actionSender:] + 75
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff8c5c18c2 -[NSController _controllerEditor:didCommit:contextInfo:] + 185
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff955c417c __invoking___ + 140
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff955c3fce -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff95663be6 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
    12  Foundation                          0x00007fff87cce345 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 377
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9563fbc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9563f853 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff956bde6a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff955facd1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1841
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff955fa338 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8add1935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8add1677 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 184
    20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8add15af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c25e0ee _DPSNextEvent + 1067
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c62a943 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c253fc8 -[NSApplication run] + 682
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c1d6520 NSApplicationMain + 1176
    25  sb_ac_doc                           0x0000000100002427 main + 87
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff987455ad start + 1
)
```

What is the correct pattern I should use so the array controller can access the MOC of the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use bindings, you have to modify properties in a KVO compliant way. Put `dynamic` in front of `var context: NSManagedObjectContext?`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the property `context` of ViewController is missing. Let's assume we have a Core Data Stack. Usually it can be generated automatically once you check `Use Core Data` option when creating a new project.

[image]

And then implementing the `managedObjectContext` which is created in `AppDelegate` for the `context` of ViewController:

```
var context: NSManagedObjectContext? {
    guard let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return nil
    }
    return appDelegate.managedObjectContext
}
```

As to other minor modification, I created a pull request via GitHub. Please take it for a reference.

Comment: I am not certain this will work for an application that will have multiple documents and therefore multiple MOC's. Why would not passing the MOC from the Document in makeWindowControllers to ViewController before the code runs that causes the crash fail?

Comment: @ericgorr I think it's about a decision making. If you prefer to passing the MOC from the Document in makeWindowControllers to ViewController, ``Prepare content`` should be unchecked in IB because storyboard loaded earlier than MOC is ready. If you prefer to keeping ``Prepare content'', you can find a tutorial from RAYWENDERLICH
: https://www.raywenderlich.com/21752/how-to-use-cocoa-bindings-and-core-data-in-a-mac-app and check the complete project. It does prepare a MOC in AppDelegate class.

Comment: The AppDelegate doesn't have a MOC. Each document has it's own MOC.